# Disable password authentication to set proxy information

Tags: gnome, proxy, authentication

To set up/change proxy settings on Ubuntu 12.04 (Gnome 3), i have to provide my admin password. Is it possible to disable this authentication? I don't need that any user could change it, just that i could change the proxy settings without being prompt my password...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a way to do this. Those settings are defined in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/com.ubuntu.systemservice.policy` file. So, to disable the password authentication  one should change the values of `allow_active` and `allow_inactive` in `com.ubuntu.systemservice.setnoproxy` and `com.ubuntu.systemservice.setnoproxy` to "yes".

This should not be the best way to do it (involves editing a xml file) but it worked.